# Get Cucumber to use the test environment in Sinatra

Tags: testing, cucumber, sinatra

This seems right, but doesn't seem to work.

#### env.rb:

```
class MyWorld
  set :environment, :test
end
```

#### app.rb:

```
configure :development do
  DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://development.sqlite3")
end

configure :test do
  DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://test.sqlite3")
end
```

It keeps using the development environment. Am I missing something, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this at the top of env.rb, and things work perfectly:

#### env.rb

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
```

Alternatively, this will do the same without having to edit any files:

```
$ RACK_ENV=test cucumber features
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the cucumber-sinatra gem. It has options to autogenerate a minimal amount of code (including your Sinatra app & rackup file). It should provide the correct syntax for getting cucumber scripts to run in test configuration.